# Can electrical flux or discharge of energy lines be shown in a photograph?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

[image][image]
Here is an image of powerlines I took and I can't figure out what the energy rings or circles is called exactly .. need input.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the type of imaging this is.  e.g. what type of camera and what sort of filter?  Also, is there a visible light photograph of the same scene?  (Side note, you cannot photograph electric field lines directly.)

Comment: Electrical field lines? ? LIke the ones in my pictures? ?

Comment: Hello @Rummyjer and welcome to Physics.SE.  The other commenter is correct: your "image" is clearly more complex than a visible-light photograph. Without more information about how you've produced these images, no one will be able to explain the circular artifacts you're asking about.  They are highly unlikely to be electric field lines, because they have to wrong shape in space for power-line fields and also, for any reasonable camera settings, the wrong time structure.